# Заполнение chart из dictionary не уникальными значениями C#

Tags: c#, словари, диаграммы

Хочу создать на форме диаграмму, которая заполняется данными из БД.
Для этого делаю следующее:

```
Dictionary<string, int> chartsource = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i<dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        { 
            chartsource.Add(dt.Rows[i]["title"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["count"]));
        }

        chart.Series.Clear();
        //Добавление нового набора данных
        chart.Series.Add(series);
        //Тип графика для данного набора данных
        chart.Series[series].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Pie;
        chart.Series[series]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Disabled";
        chart.Series[series].LegendToolTip = series;
        chart.Legends[0].Title = series;
        //Задание значений для графика
        chart.Series[series].Points.DataBindXY(chartsource.Keys, chartsource.Values);
```

Когда значения в key Dictionary уникальные, все работает отлично. Но порой встречаются повторяющиеся значения и тогда вылетает соответствующая ошибка о том, что такой ключ уже есть. С этим можно что-нибудь сделать, или dictionary придется на что-то другое менять? Если придется, то подскажите что лучше выбрать в качестве альтернативы.

Comment: какой тип у `series`?

Comment: @Bulson тип string

Comment: `Но порой встречаются повторяющиеся значения и тогда вылетает соответствующая ошибка о том, что такой ключ уже есть` - значит в цикле нужно не просто добавлять в словарь значения, а прежде проверять, есть ли такой ключ в словаре или нет. Если такой ключ есть, то видимо надо изменять значение по этому ключу в словаре, как изменять? Наверное суммировать с прежним значением, но вам виднее...

Comment: мне кажется вам нужно обыграть объектами все

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Альтернатива Вам не поможет, поскольку изначальная проблема с дубликатами ключей останется. Можно заменить цикл следующим кодом с суммированием значений по одинаковым ключам:

```
    string title;
    int val;
    for (int i = 0; i<dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    { 
        title = dt.Rows[i]["title"].ToString();
        if (chartsource.TryGetValue(title, out val))
            chartsource[title] = val + Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["count"]));
        else
            chartsource.Add(title, Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["count"]));
    }
```